# UICollectionView Scroll to next item

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, cgpoint, scroll-paging

The idea is replacing PageController with UIScrollView, UIScrollView should only scroll to the next/previous item and stop. I've found a few solutions, but I've only understood that I've to use targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset, but have no idea what CGPoint should I return and how to stop on the next item even if user scrolls with high velocity.

```
    override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UIScrollView, you can enable paging. The property is called pagingEnabled. This means if it will snap to full widths (or heights) providing you set the content size properly.

i.e. If you want 2 pages and have a width of 100 and height of 200. You set the content size to be CGSize 200 for width and 200 for height. The scroll view will handle the snapping and paging.

If you want to have a function to go to a page like goToPage(2). Then you just need to call scrollRectToVisible method in UIScrollView with a CGRect of (pageNumber * scrollView.width (or page width), 1 height)

It looks like you are using Swift, so your implementation may vary.

Comment: I like to add as I forgot you only want to move to next item is that you have a couple of options. You can stop userinteraction to the scrollview and add gestures on the main view and that will trigger a method to go to next/previous page. Or you can do is create 3 pages and display the middle. When animation has finished, you move the current view into the middle and load the next or previous views. Effectively making an infinite paging.

Comment: topCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true;
topCollectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 300.0). I've added this, paging works but is stops not on whole Cell but on some random points so I can see both previous and next cells

Comment: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width would only mean there is 1 page. As a test, try UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width*5 and see if it is paging. This should point you to the right direction

Comment: As a guide, you shouldn't need to use UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width to get the width. This could cause trouble when orientating and using different screen sizes.

Comment: might there be any problem with me using CollectionView autolayouted to underlaying scrollview? it still scrolls first approximately 200 points right, then shows me whole page, then again approximately 300 points right and so on.

Comment: You have CollectionView as SubView. If you have it underlaying, it won't be inside the scrollview and therefore not scroll. If you are using AutoLayout. Have the collectionView as a separate view with IBOutlet etc. In the Controller in the viewDidLoad, add the outlet in the scrollView as a subview. Then you need viewDidLayoutSubviews in the controller. There you will position the collectionView in the correct area in the scrollView. like page 1 would be collectionView.frame = CGSize(0,0,scrollview.width, scrollviewHeight).

Comment: yeah the problem was with layouts, fixed it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use below of code. Your problem will be solved.

```
YourScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```